# What are Array empty slots?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I ran into the following:

```
// Nothing is printed to console
Array(10).forEach(() => console.log("hi"));

// "hi" is printed 10 times
Array(10).fill(0).forEach(() => console.log("hi"));
```

Looking at [Array constructor docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), the `10` passed in corresponds to the parameter `arrayLength` with the following documentation:

> this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of `arrayLength` empty slots, not slots with actual `undefined` values)

I'm assuming `length` property indicates how much memory to allocate for the array, but what is an "empty slot" (vs. a slot with `undefined` or some default value)?

Comment: A nonexisting slot. A property that does not exist but has an integer name smaller than the `.length` of the array.

Comment: Arrays are just Objects with a special length property and inherited array methods. The *length* property does not necessarily create "empty" slots, ECMA-262 does not specify implementation so developers are free to allocate memory or not, or create empty slots, or not. [*forEach*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach) does not visit "empty" indexes.

Comment: Confusingly, calling `fill()` _without an argument_ also works, eg. `Array(10).fill()`. This produces an array with 10 slots _that reference values_ which are `undefined`; subtly different than `Array(10)` which give an array with 10 slots where _the references themselves_ are `undefined`.