# What is the difference between "Array(n)" and "[...Array(n)]"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the difference between the two?

```
// Chrome console

Array(2);                   // [undefined × 2]
Array(2).map(() => 1);      // [undefined × 2]

[...Array(2)];              // [undefined, undefined]
[...Array(2)].map(() => 1); // [1, 1]
```

Based on [What are Array empty slots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519972/what-are-array-empty-slots#comment72177471_42519972), it seems to be related to memory allocation, but why does the spread operator suddenly cause memory to be allocated in the latter case?

Comment: `[...Array(2)]` is equivalent to `[undefined, undefined]`. That's what the spread operator does.

Comment: But `[undefined × 2]` is not equivalent to `[undefined, undefined]`(?)

Comment: No it isn't, just like the question you link to (and its duplicates) says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Regarding Array constructor

All these calls are equivalent:

- `Array(2)`
- `new Array(2)`
- `var a = []; a.length = 2`

They are equal in a sense that they allocate memory for assignment, but don't create the indexes.

`Object.keys(Array(2)) // []`.

That's why when you do

`Array(2).map(() => 1);      // [undefined × 2]`

you essentially change nothing, because no iteration happens over the array, because of lack of iteration index keys that `map` uses while iterating over the array.

## Regarding spread operator

`...` operator calls the `[Symbol.iterator]`  of an array which is the built in `values()` iterator and iterates over values even with absent key indexes.

That is why in the outcome we have a new array with distinct undefined values with key indexes in place.

`Object.keys([...Array(2)]) // ["0", "1"]`.

After which `map` works as expected iterating over the keys and corresponding values.