# How to push specific number of elements into array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like the one below.

```
let array = ["Sandy", 5, 2, 7]
```

I want to push a number of blank elements at the end of the array based on a variable ("x"). If x = 3, it would add three elements to the end of the array:

```
let array = ["Sandy", 5, 2, 7, , , ]
```

I know the push method allows you to add specific elements to the end of an array. How would I achieve this? Hope this question is clear

Answer (score 2):

You could simply iterate the desired number of times and push `undefined`:

```js
function padArray(arr, num) {
    for (var i=0; i < num; ++i) {
        arr.push(undefined);
    }
}

var array = ["Sandy", 5, 2, 7];
console.log(array);
padArray(array, 3);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a for loop it's your answer,
example:

```
var array=[your array]
for(x=0;x<length of your variable;x++){
   array.push(your values to push)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var a = [1,2,3]`

> a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

`var c = Array(...a,...Array(3).fill(null))`

> c = [ 1, 2, 3, null, null, null ]

change 3 to any number you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be fancy one liner to achieve it could look like:

```js
let array = ["Sandy", 5, 2, 7]
console.log([...array, ...(new Array(3))])
```

Are tree dots looks strange? If yes - then please feel free to read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

`.concat()` would do the job

```js
let array = ["Sandy", 5, 2, 7]
let x = 3;

array = array.concat(Array(x));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I like this answer. Though I'd `fill` the new array before `concat`.

`array = array.concat(Array(x).fill(undefined));`

Comment: @KarthikSivasubramaniam why do you suggest to `fill` an Array that has only `undefined` it with `undefined`?

Comment: @t.niese It has to do with the empty elements having an index, and having to use the index for some purpose. For one, I work in React extensively where I map through child components and I almost always use the index as the key for each mapped child. If the index is not there, my keys won't be unique anymore.

Comment: Here is a generic, non-React example use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519972/what-are-array-empty-slots

The point is, pushing empty slots into an array could cause unexpected behavior of your code, unless you're aware of the subtle differences between empty slots and undefined members.

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = ["Sandy", 5, 2, 7];
var  x = 3;
for(var i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
arr.push("");
}

console.log(arr);
```

and result

```
["Sandy", 5, 2, 7, "", "", ""]
```

Comment: `""` is an empty string and that is not equal to an empty element.